# Does qt 4.5 have any skins?

Tags: qt, skins

I am developing for the first time using qt 4.5. I am developing a desktop app that will run on windows xp/vista.

The client would like to have a skin that assemblies a softphone, or something similar.

Does qt come with any skinning engine?  Is it possible to create skins using qt?

Many thanks,

Comment: have a look at this list of styles for Qt/KDE: http://www.kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=9 it may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can write [style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) to customize the look of your application. The syntax is like CSS and gives you many possibilities. If you just want all your buttons to be red, for example:

```
QPushButton {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think this isn't powerful enough for his application.

Comment: it is if he writes his widgets to get any stylistic info from the style sheet

Answer (score 6):

[Yes](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/paintsystem.html#styling). It's called styling.